# How do I force the user to become root

Tags: bash, permissions

I have written a bash script for use on my ubuntu box. Now I would like to prevent running this script under my own user and only able to run it as root (sudo).

Is there a possibility to force this. Can I somehow let my script ask for root permissions if I run it under my own username?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a standard function I use in `bash` for this very purpose:

```
# Check if we're root and re-execute if we're not.
rootcheck () {
    if [ $(id -u) != "0" ]
    then
        sudo "$0" "$@"  # Modified as suggested below.
        exit $?
    fi
}
```

There's probably more elegant ways (I wrote this AGES ago!), but this works fine for me.

To use this function consistently in a script, you should pass it the arguments received by the script originally.

Usage: `rootcheck "${@}"`  (`rootcheck` alone will not pass any arguments to the rootcheck function)

Comment: Possibly `exec sudo "$0" "$@"` to avoid problems with spaces in arguments, and avoid have the first execution hanging around?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a decided improvement.  I'll update the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Note that if it's run as a function like this, you need to pass in the script's parameters (i.e. run it with `rootcheck "$@"`).  Or you can just put the if block inline rather than in a function.  Also, this should be done very early in the script, as anything before it will be run twice (once normally, once as root).

Comment: I do it first thing in the script, so yeah.  Early is right.

Comment: It's sometimes good to run sanity checks (e.g. does the file in question exist?) before sudo'ing -- I tend to do this by starting the script with something like `if [[ $1 == "--no-sanity-checks" ]]; then shift; else run sanity checks; fi` and then modify the sudo command to `exec sudo "$0" --no-sanity-checks "$@"`

Answer (score 5):

i am using this single line version, easy to copy paste on top of scripts

```
[ `whoami` = root ] || { sudo "$0" "$@"; exit $?; }
```

Comment: This would work, but it creates a dependency on `sudo`. It's probably better form to just check `$EUID` and quit if not root.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chown root yourcode
sudo chmod 500 yourcode
```

Voila!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the permissions, so that only root can execute it.
Or you could use `whoami` command and in case that it isn't root force sudo.